# How to Install pip using python2 / Python (2.x)?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, openssl

I tried to install libosmesa-devel for my EulerOS. It required Python (2.x) pip to install some packages. I already had python3 installed; so, I installed python2. Then, I got stuck while trying to install pip using python2. The general instruction was to download get-pip.py and run the following command:

```
python2 get-pip.py
```

which generates the following error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError('_ssl.c:710: The handshake operation timed out',),)) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
```

For the first line of error - SSL certificate error, I tried two approaches:

1. I rebuild the python-2.7.15-1.x86_64.rpm with `./configure --with-ssl`; Did NOT work.
2. I followed along the following reddit thread but this is from 2021 and I think it is outdated: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/s98n25/comment/htlc7wf/

I tried to use `--index-url http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org` arguments to resolve the first error but it did not work.

Comment: Is there a reason you need Python 2?  I'm not sure PyPI still provides packages for Python 2 since it went End of Life.

Comment: I am trying to install libosmesa-devel.x86_64 from the source for EulerOS which required Python2 and you are right - PyPI does not provide packages for python2 after pip20.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first line of error -

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError('_ssl.c:710: The handshake operation timed out',),)) - skipping
```

Solution: Change `https` to `http` in the
 `--index-url http://pypi.python.org/simple/`

So, run ==>

```
python2 get-pip.py --index-url http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

But this did not solve the following errors -

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
```

Solution:
Download the following three files from the given links:

1. [pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/79/8a850fe3496446ff0d584327ae44e7500daf6764ca1a382d2d02789accf7/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl)
2. [setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/b7/182161210a13158cd3ccc41ee19aadef54496b74f2817cc147006ec932b4/setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl)
3. [wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/d6/003e593296a85fd6ed616ed962795b2f87709c3eee2bca4f6d0fe55c6d00/wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl)

Put these files in the same folder as `get-pip.py` and run the following command:

```
python2 get-pip.py "pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl" "setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl" "wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl" --index-url http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

This finally solved the problem!

```
Successfully installed pip-20.3.4 setuptools-44.1.1 wheel-0.37.1
```